# Issue with compiling C code on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. for Windows using MinGW-w64 cross-compiler

Tags: windows, ubuntu, openssl, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a C code on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, targeting Windows, using the `MinGW-w64` cross-compilation toolchain. However, I'm encountering an error related to the OpenSSL headers not being found during the compilation process.

I have already installed the `libssl-dev` package, which should provide the necessary headers.

```bash
snave@1080gems:~/Izoh$ ls /usr/include/openssl |grep ssl
opensslv.h
ossl_typ.h
prov_ssl.h
ssl.h
ssl2.h
ssl3.h
sslerr.h
sslerr_legacy.h
```

I even added  openssl location  when running it:
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o crypto.exe crypto.c -lssl -lcrypto -I/usr/include/openssl -L/usr/lib -lws2_32` 
*--I Searched online how to do that.*

But I'm still getting the error:
`fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory` 
Am I missing something in the compilation process?

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added

```
I/usr/include/openssl
```

and one of your error messages is

```
 fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
```

When you added `I/usr/include/openssl`, files will be searched from that point.  The `#include <openssl/rsa.h>` line will cause the compiler to look for the file

```
/usr/include/openssl/openssl/rsa.h
```

which doesn't exist.  You need to

1. Use the standard `-I/usr/include` path and not `-I/usr/include/openssl`
2. Include OpenSSL headers in your code with `#include <openssl/rsa.h>` and not `#include <rsa.h>`

For example, see [this OpenSSL documentation for `RSA_free()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_free.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <openssl/rsa.h>
>
> RSA *RSA_new(void);
>
> void RSA_free(RSA *rsa);
> ```

Note it's `#include <openssl/rsa.h>`.